# Problema al guardar las preferencias con sharedPreferences

Tags: mysql, android-studio, recyclerview

Buen día, tengo un problema al guardar las preferencias en Android Studio resulta que tengo un contador de productos el cual se incrementa cada vez que yo agrego un producto, cuando termino de agregar los productos aplico el método `SharedPreferences` para que me guarde el estado del contador del carrito por ejemplo si yo agregue 3 productos cuando viaje a la pantalla donde lleno los productos (En este caso estoy utilizando un `RecyclerView` para llenarlo de productos debido a que estoy trabajando con `MySQL` para obtener los productos). Bueno hasta aquí todo perfecto no tengo problema, el problema radica cuando yo quiero eliminar un producto, si yo tengo 3 productos agregados por ejemplo y quiero eliminar 2 productos, en el carrito deberían aparecer 2 productos al momento de regresar a la pantalla de productos, sin embargo el contador del carrito conserva su estado en 3 productos, esto debido a que, cuando yo viajo a la pantalla donde obtengo los productos el contador guarda su estado en 3 y no cambia.
A continuación muestro el código relacionado a este problema.

En mi clase "ObtenerExamenes" es donde guardo el estado del carrito al momento de dar al botón del carrito.

```
public void saveData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(TEXT, tvCantProductos.getText().toString());
    editor.clear().apply();
    editor.apply();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Datos guardados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void loadData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    text = sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT, "0");
}

public void updateViews(){
    tvCantProductos.setText(text);
}
```

Y este es el botón donde llamo el método `saveData()` para guardar el estado.

```
int carrito = Integer.parseInt(tvCantProductos.getText().toString());
        tvCantProductos.setText(String.valueOf(carrito));

        if (carrito < 1){

            Toast.makeText(this, "Porfavor agrega algunos exámenes antes de continuar.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            
            saveData();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, TicketDatos.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Por ultimo esta mi clase adaptador, si vamos al grano exactamente en el botón eliminar tengo asignado un pequeño código para decrementar el carrito de compras en 1 cada vez que yo elimino un producto el cual es el siguiente.

```
holder.btnEliminar.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        int decremento = Integer.parseInt(ObtenerProductos.tvCantProductos.getText().toString());
        decremento = decremento - 1;
        AdaptadorProductos.tvCantProductos.setText(String.valueOf(decremento)); });
```

EN RESUMEN: **Mientras el estado del contador este guardado este no decrementara cuando yo elimine un producto, nose si existe alguna forma de eliminar el estado del contador mientras este en la pantalla de los productos**

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Para que el valor actualizado se cambie deberías  modificar el contenido del valor guardado en SharedPreferences, lo cual no estás haciendo. Tu estás guardando el valor en el Adaptador, pero no en el archivo. Por otra parte, si es para una aplicación final, esto no es recomendable hacerlo con SharedPreferences, el cual está más destinado a guardar cosas muy concretas (como valores de configuración por ejemplo), para datos tan dinámicos como un carrito, productos, etc sería mejor usar una base de datos.

Comment: Comprendo, si creo que es mejor utilizar la base de datos gracias por la sugerencia!!